# I have swum in sea since 2015

Tags: since

With "since", I can talk about 1) something which started in the past and which continues up to the present, 2) something which happened one or several times in the past.

1) I have worked for this company since 2015. (I have been working for this company since 2015.)

2) I have swum in sea since 2015. ( I have swum once or twice since 2015. It is not meant for continual swimming. )

Am I right?

Comment: *I have been swimming since 2015* would be used to refer to occasional swimming, regular swimming, **or** continual swimming. Literal continual swimming for 5 years, while factually impossible, is still not ungrammatical.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe my question is not clear. I am not asking about that. I am asking about whether or not I can talk about 2) something which happened only several times in the past with the word SINCE.

Comment: My comment addressed any number of occurrences: occasional, regular, and continual. (I only expanded on *continual* because you had mentioned it.) Several times is occasional. Between **then** and **now**, you have been swimming occasionally …

Comment: 'Since' doesn't convey 'once or twice'. You would have to say, 'I've swum in the sea once or twice since 2015.' But it depends on context. If I tell you I haven't swum in the sea since 2015, you can then say, "I have. I've swum in the sea since 2015."

Comment: @Xanne Why do you discourage the use of "since" in sentence 2? How is it misused ?

Comment: Since is often used to convey regular habits, which occur more often than once or twice.