# I have bought a computer since last year

Tags: present-perfect, since

Does the sentences mean I still have the computer?

> I've bought a computer since last year.
>
> I've bought a computer this year.
>
> I've bought a computer this month.

Comment: Closely related: [I've bought a car since last year; I've learnt to swim since 2017](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/249821/ive-bought-a-car-since-last-year-ive-learnt-to-swim-since-2017/249846#249846)

Comment: Also related: **1.** [I have swum in sea since 2015](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/247794) **2.** [She has been living in Berlin since 2009, but she doesn't any more](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/249857) **3.** [I have done something since 2018. (present perfect with SINCE)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/248261)

Comment: Please read the accepted answer posted on: [It has been a long time since I visited you /since I used to visit you/since I have visited you](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/97059)

Answer (score 1):

The OP's sentence “*I've bought a computer since last year*” is not idiomatic. The Present Perfect and the Present Perfect Continuous are often used with *since* when it indicates either a specific point in the past at which something happened and did not continue, or a point in the past **that signals when an event started**.

> ## [since](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/since)  (*preposition*)
>
> in the time after (a specified time or event in the past): from (a point in the past) until the present time
>
> - I haven't seen him *since* yesterday.
> - I haven't eaten *since* breakfast.
> - *Since* the party, she has not spoken to him at all.
> - We've been waiting for you *since* 10 o'clock.
> - The company started as a small local business 10 years ago and has grown a lot **since then**. [=within that time]

Source *Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary*

> I've bought a computer this week/month/year.

This denotes a SINGLE action. The purchase was **completed at a certain point in the past**. The person is not currently buying that same computer a day, a week or several years later. Moreover, the time expression “*this* week/month/year” refers to a period of time that is not yet concluded. Consequently, **the reader will surmise that the buyer now possesses the product.**  In fact, the present perfect is used for actions that were completed in the past but have an effect in the present, e.g. *She's cut* her finger. (*Now* her finger is bleeding.), *We've finished* paying off the mortgage (*Now* we no longer have to pay back the bank.), The government *has raised* income taxes for the second time  (*Now* workers have less spending money.)

However, when consumers cannot afford to purchase an item, they may decide to pay *monthly installments*. In which case, the present perfect continuous is often used **for actions repeated over a period of time.**

> I'**ve been paying** for my car in installments *since* last year.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about "since". You said  “I've bought a computer since last year” was not idiomatic, but you haven't explained why it was not idiomatic.

Comment: It's not idiomatic because it is not something a native speaker would say. It is understandable, and maybe in casual speech it *might* be possible to hear it being used but it would not be acceptable in formal exams and with the majority of English speaking people.

Comment: Is this sentence idiomatic: I've been to Japan since 2017.

Comment: If I want to say I bought a computer at an unspecified point between last year and now, what should I say?

Comment: @StephenLiu  *I **bought** a computer last year*. OR *I **bought** a new computer last month* OR *I **got** a new computer in January/February* etc.. The person who has bought the item  knows *when* it was bought. If  more than one computer was bought in a recent period then someone could say "*I'**ve bought** two computers **since 2017*** "
that will suggest they will buy another one in the very near future.

Comment: "Have you travelled anywhere since 2017?"  "Since 2017 I have been to Japan and India", "since 2017 I have been to Japan twice or "I went to Japan in 2017".

Comment: @StephenLiu Of course, I should have thought of it earlier: *I'**ve had** this computer since 2017* The focus is on the length of time it has been **owned** not  when it was purchased.